# ios URL trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I am trying to get an Amazon search of movie titles but am having trouble with the URL. The movie name is inserted into the link with '%@', but the extra '%' is causing a problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Errors:

```
More '%' conversions than data arguments
Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'NSString *'
```

Here is my code:

```
- (void)jumpToAmazon:(id)sender {
    // create the string that points to the correct Amazon page for the game name
    NSString *amazonPageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Dmovies-tv&field-keywords=%@&sprefix=friend%2Cmovies-tv&rh=i%3Amovies-tv%2Ck%3A%@", self.movie.name, self.movie.name];
    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:amazonPageString]])
    {
        // there was an error trying to open the URL. for the moment we'll simply ignore it.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double up literal percents like this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:
@"http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%%3Dmovies-tv&field-keywords=%@&sprefix=friend%%2Cmovies-tv&rh=i%%3Amovies-tv%%2Ck%%3A%@",
self.movie.name, self.movie.name];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `%%` when you want an actual percent sign to appear in the string.

Answer (score 1):

At the spot in the URL `url=search-alias%3Dmovies-tv` you need to add another % sign to make it look like `url=search-alias%%3Dmovies-tv`. The same goes with`friend%2Cmovies-tv&rh=i%3Amovies-tv%2Ck%3`, you need to change that to `friend%%2Cmovies-tv&rh=i%%3Amovies-tv%%2Ck%%3` in order for it to print the percent sign.